# How do I run a Python script with sudo? (MAC)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, sudo

I want to test the `keyboard.on_press_key()` function, but OSX blocks it naturally. When I try to run it through the terminal using `sudo python [pathtofile]` I get an import error: "ImportError: No module named keyboard". I tried installing the module using sudo (`sudo pip install keyboard`) but, even though it installs just fine, I still get the same error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have several Pythons installed? Try `python -m pip install keyboard`

Comment: @tobias ```python -m pip install keyboard``` made it work, thank you. What is the difference between ```pip install```and ```python -m pip install```?

Comment: By running that, you make sure that it is the `pip` corresponding to your `python` (since you're running it via your selected Python interpreter). But: check out my answer for some useful information about your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `python` on macOS refers to the system installation. You should not install packages via `pip` to the system installation of Python. I'd recommend you to install another Python interpreter e.g. via `brew`. See [www.brew.sh](http://www.brew.sh) for more info.

Then, it is just a matter of installing Python via

```sh
$ brew install python3
```

After that, simply install your `keyboard` package again:

```sh
$ pip3 install keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a error in your script, you probably didnt import the keyboard module before you used. Try adding this in the first lines of your python script:

```
 import keyboard
```